# peilcan, pagination for just rss

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

I have a pelican blog and I love it. I love it so much that I've written so many blogposts that my RSS feed has gotten rather heavy. I like to keep all the titles of my blogpost on my front page, but I like my RSS feed light.

Is there a way to turn on pagination for *just* RSS on pelican?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of items in your feed, pelican has the [`FEED_MAX_ITEMS`](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html#feed-settings) setting.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following Pelican Plugin : https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/feed_summary

And then add this to your `pelicanconf.py`:

```
PLUGIN_PATH = '/path/to/pelican-plugins'
PLUGINS = [
    'feed_summary',
    ]
FEED_USE_SUMMARY = True
```

This will lighten a lot your rss feeds

Comment: But this will not list the latest x posts, instead it will just make all the posts in the RSS feed shorter. It seems better to post less posts than to still post all of them, no?

Comment: not all rss readers read the entire post, so i might still make the rss feed better by making the text shorter. the solution is good enough.